# New Transaction cannot enlist the specified transactional coordinator?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I did followed these steps in my BizTalk server, but nothing cleared my error Can any one suggest be the way to rectify.
FYI, I am using BizTalk server 2006 R2 in windows server 2003, and SQL server 2005.

I am fetching data from SQL, My BizTalk interface works in my UAT environment but not in production server.What may be the reasons I have followed these steps .Please suggest me rectification method,any help is welcomed.

Step: 1

Click Start-> RUN, type Dcomcnfg.exe and click OK. Do the following changes. Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC\Security.

```
Sl. No  MSDTC Security  Values to be given
1   Network DTC Access  1
2   Network DTC Access Admin    1
3   Network DC Access clients   1
4   Network DTC Access Inbound  1
5   Network DTC Access Outbound 1
6   Network DTC Access Tip  1
7   Network DTC Access Transaction  1
8   XaTransaction   1
```

Step: 2

Click Start-> RUN, type Dcomcnfg.exe and click OK. Do the following changes. Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC.
Sl. No  MSTDC   Values to be given
1   Allow Only Security RPC Calls   0
2   Fallback to unsecure RPC, If necessary  0
3   Turn Off RPC Security   1

Step: 3

Click Start-> Run, type regedit, and click OK. Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\
Software\Microsoft\MSDTC.

Right click MSDTC, point to new, and then click DWORD Value. Type CmMaxNumberBindRetries, and then press ENTER.

Right click CmMaxNumberBindRetries, and then click Modify. Click Decimal.
In the value data box, Type 60.

This value increases the length of time that the client computer waits for the bind packet response from the server computer. This value is double the number of seconds before the client computer stops the transaction if the client computer does not receive the bind packet response. For example, a value of 60 equals 30 seconds.

Note: The value of 60 is only a recommended value. Additional testing on your configuration may be required.
Click OK. Restart MS DTC.

Step: 4

A)   Start->settings->control panel->administration tools->
           1. Services-> Re start Distributed transactional coordinator.
           2. Services->right click->properties->set start up type to automatic.

B)   Start->settings->control panel->Add or remove programs->Add/Remove Windows Components->Click Application server-> details-> check the enable network DTC Access & enable com+ components.

C)   Try restarting MSDTC by Run -> cmd->type
            1. Net stop MSDTC,
            2. Net start MSDTC.

D)  Start->settings->control panel->administration tools->
            1. Component services->computers->my computers->right click -> properties->MSTDC

E)   Final step is to uninstall and install MSDTC in both SQL server and BizTalk server.

F)   Verify and confirm that firewall doesn't block any port.
any help is welcomed.

Comment: Try following some of the advice on this link http://www.remotedbaexperts.com/Blog/2011/01/troubleshooting-biztalk-dtc-issues-with-dtcping-and-dtctest/  Have you used the dtc ping tool and dtc test tools to investigate your issue futher?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error until I add the SQL Server NetBIOS name to host file in my BizTalk Server, and does the opposite at the SQL Server.

For my setup environment, the BizTalk Server is querying data from the SQL Server connected through WANG.